# Complex numbers and missing arguments in R function

Tags: r, arguments

I am solving a task for my R online course. The task is to write a function, that solves the quadratic equation with the Lagrange resolvents, or:

```
x1<--p/2+sqrt((p/2)^2-q)
x2<--p/2-sqrt((p/2)^2-q)
```

1) If the arguments are non-numeric, the function should return an explained error (or why the error has happend). 2) If there are missing arguments, the function should return an explained error (different from the default). 3) If x1 and x2 are complex numbers (for example if p=-4 and q=7, then x1=2+i*1.73 and x2=2-i*1.73), the function should should also solve the equation instead of generating NaNs and return a warning message, that the numbers are complex. Maybe if I somehow cast it to as.complex, but I want this to be a special case and don't want to cast the basic formula.

My function looks like this:

```
quadraticEquation<-function(p,q){
 if(!is.numeric(c(p,q)))stop("p and q are not numeric") #partly works
 if(is.na(c(p,q)))stop("there are argument/s missing") #does not work
 x1<--p/2+sqrt((p/2)^2-q)
 x2<--p/2-sqrt((p/2)^2-q)
 #x1<--p/2+sqrt(as.complex((p/2)^2-q)) works, but I want to perform this only in case the numbers are complex
 #x2<--p/2-sqrt(as.complex((p/2)^2-q))
 return (c(x1,x2))
}
```

When testing the function:

```
quadraticEquation(4,3) #basic case is working
quadraticEquation(TRUE,5) #non-numeric, however the if-statement is not executed, because it assumes that TRUE==1
quadraticEquation(-4,7) #complex number
```

1) how to write the function, so it assumes TRUE (without "") and anything that is non-numeric as non-numeric?
2) basic case, works.
3) how can I write the function, so it solves the equation and prints the complex numbers and also warns that the numbers are complex (warning())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
quadraticEquation <- function(p, q){
  ## ------------------------% chek the arguments %---------------------------##
  if(
    missing(p) | missing(q)                              # if any of arguments is 
  ){                                                     # missing - stop.
    stop("[!] There are argument/s missing")
  }
  else if(
    !is.numeric(p) | !is.numeric(q) | any(is.na(c(p, q))) # !is.numeric(c(1, T))
  ){                                                     # returns TRUE - conver-    
    stop("[!] Argument/s p or/and q are not numeric")    # tion to the same type
  }
  ## --------------------% main part of the function %--------------------------##  
  r2 <- p^2 - 4*q                                        # calculate r^2,
  if(r2 < 0){                                            # if r2 < 0 (convert) it 
    warning("equation has complex roots")                # to complex and warn
    r2 <- as.complex(r2)
  }
                                                         # return named roots
  setNames(c(-1, 1) * sqrt(r2)/2 - p/2, c("x1", "x2"))
}

quadraticEquation()                                      # No arguments provided
#Error in quadraticEquation() : [!] There are argument/s missing
quadraticEquation(p = 4)                                 # Argument q is missing
#Error in quadraticEquation(p = 4) : [!] There are argument/s missing
quadraticEquation(p = TRUE, q = 7)                       # p is logical
#Error in quadraticEquation(p = TRUE, q = 7) : 
#[!] Argument/s p or/and q are not numeric
quadraticEquation(p = NA, q = 7)                         # p is NA
#Error in quadraticEquation(p = NA, q = 7) : 
#[!] Argument/s p or/and q are not numeric
quadraticEquation(p = 7, q = -4)                         # real roots
#        x1         x2 
#-7.5311289  0.5311289 
quadraticEquation(p = -4, q = 7)                         # complex roots
#         x1          x2 
#2-1.732051i 2+1.732051i
#Warning message:
#In quadraticEquation(p = -4, q = 7) : equation has complex roots
```

Comment: Awesome solution! Can I ask how to return vector with only one element (x1) in case x1 and x2 are equal (for example when p=-4 and q=4)?

Comment: maybe try `unique()` it will return unique values, so `unique(c(1, 1)) returns `1`

Comment: Does not work, returns error in setNames: argument "nm" is missing, with no default. (what is this argument nm?)

Comment: Yes, sorry, poor thinking. So divide it like this: 
- Calculate the roots: `roots <-   unique(c(-1, 1) * sqrt(r2)/2 - p/2)`;
- Then set names and return: `setNames(roots, paste0("x", 1:length(roots)))`
Another alternative, just return `unique(c(-1, 1)*sqrt(r2)/2 - p/2)` so it will be unnamed vector.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `is.numeric(c(p, q))`, R first evaluates `c(p, q)` before determining whether it is numeric or not. In particular if `p = TRUE` and `q = 3`, then `c(p, q)` is promoted to the higher type: `c(1, 3)`.

Here is a vectorized solution, so if `p` and `q` are vectors instead of scalars the result is also a vector.

```
quadraticEquation <- function(p, q) {
  if (missing(p)) {
    stop("`p` is missing.")
  }
  if (missing(q)) {
    stop("`q` is missing.")
  }
  if (!is.numeric(p)) {
    stop("`p` is not numeric.")
  }
  if (!is.numeric(q)) {
    stop("`q` is not numeric.")
  }
  if (anyNA(p)) {
    stop("`p` contains NAs.")
  }
  if (anyNA(q)) {
    stop("`q` contains NAs.")
  }

  R <- p^2 / 4 - q

  if (min(R) < 0) {
    R <- as.complex(R)
    warning("Returning complex values.")
  }

  list(x1 = -p / 2 + sqrt(R),
       x2 = -p / 2 - sqrt(R))
}
```

Also, you should never write `x1<--p/2`. Keep spaces around infix operators: `x1 <- -p/2`.